# How can I get the hidden value?

Tags: jquery

I have one `Input.hidden` in a `foreach`, how can I get the different values?

```
<% foreach (var archivos in Model.archivosAdjuntos) { %>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <%= Html.ActionLink( NAME OF A FILE )%> &nbsp;&nbsp;       
    <input id="DELETE" name="DELETE" value="DELETE" type="button" class="DELETE"/>
    <br /><br />
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model=>hidden id of a file, new { @class="hidden_hiddenFile"}) %>  
  </div>
<% } %>
```

I try to get the hidden value:

```
  $(".DELETE").click(function () {
        alert($(this).parent().next().attr("value"));
```

but the result of the alert is `UNDEFINED`.

Comment: are there any more inputs next to this one?

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML

Comment: Just FYI: the `id` attribute needs to be unique.

Comment: no, there is the only one input

Comment: but, i called by the class. the 'id' will be repeat because the foreach

Comment: @Idalio: I know this isn't the issue, I'm just informing you that repeating `id`s on a page is bad.  `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent()` is going to get you the `myDiv` div.

`.next()` will get the next `myDiv` div.

`.attr("value")` won't work, because the div doesn't have a value.

I'm assuming you want the hidden value that's next to the input you clicked on, not the next input.

You should do something like:

```
$(this).next('.hidden_hiddenFile').attr("value")
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, was actually what you said and it worked. Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but you might have missed calling children() on the parent. Maybe something like this would work:

```
alert($(this).parent().children('.hidden_hiddenFile').attr('value'));
```

*Edit:* Rocket's selector makes more sense, you don't actually need to select the parent first.